# why do I get cannot find symbol error in vsc?

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

here I'm using vsc to run a simple java code

why I'm getting this error?

[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PVSgY.png)

```
main.java:5: error: cannot find symbol
        Array numbers = new Array(3);
        ^
  symbol:   class Array
  location: class Main
```

**here is the main and array class**

main.java

```
package main;

class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Array numbers = new Array(3);
        numbers.insert(2);
        numbers.print();
    }
}
```

Array.java

```
package main;

public class Array {
    int[] array;

    public Array(int length) {

        int[] array = new int[length];

    }

    public void insert(int item) {

        array[array.length] = item;
    }

    public void print() {
        System.out.println(array);
    }

}
```

Comment: it seems Array class has not compiled in vscode , first compile that class and run main class

Comment: I did compile the Array class and still have the same issue

Answer (score 4):

Please run it in **Java Process Console** instead of Code Runner, also pay attention to some code:

```
public class Array {
    int[] array;

    public Array(int length) {

        int[] array = new int[length];

    }
```

Here's a duplicate array definition, then running the main function will cause `NullPointerException`;

```
public void insert(int item) {

        array[array.length] = item;
    }
```

The array index is `from 0 to length-1`, so `array[array.length]` will cause `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`;

The final code running in **Java Process Console** should be

[image]